# Using a function while slicing

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for some clarification and some direction here

--Given a simple Pandas data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['123abc','456xyz'],columns=['foo'])

foo

0   123abc

1   456xyz
```

--This works

```
df.foo.str[:3]

0    123

1    456
```

--This does not

```
df.foo.str[:df.foo.str.len()]

0   NaN

1   NaN
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are attempting here, the function `df.foo.str.len()` returns a Series for each row's length, this cannot be used in the slicing syntax as it's meaningless hence the empty rows.

Comment: In your example the Series would be a Series of 2 rows of 6 value. What are you trying to achieve or are you confused by something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Ok that makes sense.  I'm trying to shorten (123abc to 123) a string by slicing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Either apply a regex pattern or apply a function that returns the characters you want, even if length did work, it'll just return the length of each row which is no different to doing nothing. You've not clarified the requirement, are you just wanting numbers only? Is the number length fixed etc..

Comment: i want to shorten some variable length strings that have a common 'suffix' length Examples: 123abc to 123 OR 45abc to 45).

Comment: I posted an answer but it is still unclear to me, is the suffix length fixed and has nothing to do with the fact you have a mixture of digits and alpha characters? OR you basically just want to slice from beginning to up to last 3 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to extract just the numbers from the strings then you can use `extract`:

```
In [23]:

df = pd.DataFrame(['123abc','45xyz'],columns=['foo'])
df.foo.str.findall(r'\d+').str[0]

Out[23]:
0    123
1     45
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

If you just want to slice from beginning of the string up to the last 3 characters then you can use a negative offset:

```
In [25]:

df = pd.DataFrame(['123abc','45xyz'],columns=['foo'])
df.foo.str[:-3]

Out[25]:
0    123
1     45
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

Comment: wow, I feel dumb.  Completely forgot about the negative offset.  Thx Ed